# Problem when executing a function

Tags: c++, xcode4

I'm trying to run a simple C++ program (as I'm JUST starting to learn C++) and tried this example code off a website as a program that adds two numbers together. When I execute the program, I never get errors, but c always returns as 0. Help??

```
#include <iostream.h>

int Add (int x, int y)
{

    std::cout << "In Add(), received " << x << " and " << y << "\n";
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "I'm in main()!\n";
    int a, b, c;
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers here: ";
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    std::cout << "\nCalling Add()\n";
    c=Add(a,b);
    std::cout << "\nBack in main().\n";
    std::cout << "c was set to " << c;
    std::cout << "\nExiting...\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Add` returns 0, `c` will *always* be 0.  You need to, you know, actually add the numbers you pass into `Add` and return *that* from the function.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a whirl. NOTE: Add returns (x+y)

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int Add(int x, int y)
    {
         std::cout << "In Add(), received " << x << " and " << y << std::endl;
         return (x+y);
    }

    int main()
    {
         std::cout << "I'm in main()!\n";
         int a, b, c;
         std::cout << "Enter two numbers: ";
         std::cin >> a;
         std::cin >> b;
         std::cout << "\nCalling Add()\n";
         c=Add(a,b);
         std::cout << "\nBack in main().\n";
         std::cout << "c was set to " << c;
         std::cout << "\nExiting...\n\n";
         return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Add` function always returns 0, so it's a mystery why `c` is always 0? :) It should be `return x + y`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised I didn't notice that earlier, but I get it now :)